# Ways of finding average accelleration

Tags: homework-and-exercises, kinematics

So I had a little debate with a professor on a simple problem of motion (See section). It basically comes down to how to find average acceleration. I did some research and couldn't find a definite answer.

He claims that the equations of motion:
 $$x = x_i + v_it+0.5at^2$$ $$v_f^2 = v_i^2+2a\Delta x$$ only work for finding average acceleration, if the acceleration is constant (thus redundant).  However, the equation $$v_f = at + v_i$$ works for finding average acceleration, regardless of $a$ being constant. Is he correct?

**Problem**:

You and your little brother are rolling toy cars back and forth to each other across the floor. He is sitting at $x = 0$, and you are at $x = 4.0 $ $m$. You roll a car toward him, giving it an initial speed of $2.1$ $m/s$ . It stops just as it reaches him in $3.0$ $s$.

To find the accelleration the obvious answer is ${0-2.1 \over 3} = -0.7$ $m/s^2$ using $v_f = at + v_i$, and that's what the book says. However, (not having done physics in a full year), I choose the less simple way and used the equation: $v_f^2 = v_i^2+2a\Delta x$.

So: $0 = 2.1^2+2a(4)$, then $a = -2.1^2/8 \approx -0.55$ $m/s^2$.

Two completely different answers. So now I argue that this situation can never be, because when you use $x = x_i + v_it+0.5at^2$, for this problem: $0 \not= 4 + 2.1*3-0.5*0.7*3^2$.

Moreso, is this problem realistic (assuming that acceleration was actually $0.7$ $m/s^2$)?

Comment: Average acceleration is total change in speed divided by the time in which it takes place. If the speed is 0 to start with, and 3 second later it is 2.1 then, yes, the average acceleration is 0.7. However, that is *average* acceleration. If the acceleration was 2.1 for one second, and it coasted for an additional two seconds, the average over the 3 seconds would still be 0.7.

Comment: Thanks, that helps partially. I suppose my real question is do the equations ($x = ...$ nd $v_f^2 = ...$ work with average acceleration.

Answer (score 2):

Well let's try and derive it:

$$v=u+\langle a\rangle t $$

holds because your professor says so. Now try and integrate:

$$ s=ut+\int\langle a \rangle t dt $$

If $a $ is a constant that we get $s=ut+0.5at^2$ and combining with $v=u+at$ to eliminate $t$ we should get $v^2=u^2+2as$. But, if $a$ is not a constant then $\langle a\rangle $ is a function of time and the method breaks down so don't expect $v^2=u^2+2\langle a\rangle s$ to hold.